# Custom Back Button for Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I made a category of `UINavigationBar` as follow:

`UINavigationBar (UINavBar_Category)`

I want to create custom back button using this.

I can able to set image by following code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Problem** can not able to change title of back button.

**My try**

```
 - (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:lang(@"btnBack") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.topItem.backBarButtonItem=backButton;
}
```

Help me to solve this!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try this code instead..  Here a button is first created , its title and image is set and then it is set as left bar button item of navigation controller.

```
UIButton *backBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 29)];

[backBarButton setTitle:@"  Log Out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [backBarButton setImage:[UIImage 
imageNamed:@"leftarrow_ipad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backBarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBarButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... I tried your code but not able to see the change.

Comment: I tried your code . It is working for me . I have added a screenshot in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     if([self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] != self)
        {
            UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 26)];
            [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // some image
            [backButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
            [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewControllerWithAnimation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            UIBarButtonItem *barBackItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackItem;

        }
     }
    -(void)popViewControllerWithAnimation
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```